# Creating backbone views with models from other views

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

**Background:**

I am making changes to an application that uses backbone.js with Handlebars as the templating engine. After a change event fires I need to create html that is appended to the current DOM structure which is basically just a spit-out of information that is contained in the model.  This change needed to fit in the already established application structure.

**Issue:**

I have created a new view that uses a Handlebars template and the model to create the html.  I then instantiate that view and call the render function and append the output using JQuery.  What I am noticing is that when the html is rendered the model that is passed in because attributes on the $el instead of filling in the template (like I think it should).

**View I'm altering:**

```
$.hart.TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#templateOne').html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('change', function () {
            this.createMoreInfoHtml();
        }, this);
    },
    selectSomething: function () {
        this.$el.removeClass('policies');

        this.createMoreInfoHtml(); //function created for new view stuff
    },
    createMoreInfoHtml: function () {
        var id = this.$el.attr('data-id', this.model.get("ID"));
        $('.info').each(function () {
            if ($(this).parent().attr('data-id') == id 
                $(this).remove();
        });

        var view = new $.hart.NewView(this.model, Handlebars.compile($("#NewTemplate").html()));
        $('h1', this.$el).after(view.render().el);
    },
    render: function () {
        ... //render logic
    }
});
```

**View I Created:**

```
$.hart.NewView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (model, template) {
            this.model = model;
            this.template = template;
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template({ info: this.model }));
            this.$el.addClass('.info');
            return this;
        }
    });
```

**Json the is the model:**

```
{
        "PetName":"Asdfasdf", 
        "DateOfBirth":"3/11/2011 12:00:00 AM",      
        "IsSpayNeutered":false, 
        "Sex":"F", 
        "SpeciesID":2, 
        "ID":"ac8a42d2-7fa7-e211-8ef8-000c2964b571"
    }
```

**The template**

```
<script id="NewTemplate" type="text/html">
        <span>Pet Name: </span>
        <span>{{this.PetName}}</span>
    </script>
```

So now to the question: What am I doing wrong?  Why are the properties of the model being created as attributes on the $el instead of filling in the template?  Can someone please direct me as to how to get the results I am looking for?

Comment: Are you forgetting to call [toJSON()](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-toJSON) on your model?, for example `this.template(this.model.toJSON())`

Comment: @Jack, Ok, I was NOT doing that.  Doing this filled in the values but I still have the issue of it also creating attributes on the element that contain those values as well. This is definitely a start though! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's skip the problem Jack noticed.
The way you're creating your view is just wrong. It may work as you get the expected arguments in the initialize function, but it has unexpected behaviors you don't see. See the View's constructor:

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
  this._configure(options || {});
```

Now let's have a look at this `_configure` method:

```
_configure: function(options) {
  if (this.options) options = _.extend({}, _.result(this, 'options'), options);
  _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
```

And of course...

```
var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'];
```

Ok here we are... Basically when passing the model as the `options` argument, you're passing an object with an `attributes` key (the attributes of your model). But this `attributes` key is also used in the View to bind attributes to its element! Therefore the behavior your noticed.

Now, other wrong thing. You're compiling your template each time you create a new function, but not using it as a singleton either. Put your template in the view:

```
$.hart.NewView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile($("#NewTemplate").html(),
```

And change your view's creation to make the whole thing work:

```
new $.hart.NewView({model: this.model});
```

Oh, and get rid of this useless `initialize` method. You're just doing things Backbone already does.